# 2d array in numpy with different data types

Tags: arrays, numpy, types

I'm trying to make a 2d array with different data types per column.  I try to do this in df, but it ends up having tuples. I want it to be like df2, but I want to specify the data type per column. This should be possible right?

```
df = np.zeros([2],dtype='uint32,''uint32')
df: array([(0, 0), (0, 0)], dtype=[('f0', '<u4'), ('f1', '<u4')])


df2 =np.zeros([2,2],dtype='uint32') 
df2: array([[0, 0],
       [0, 0]], dtype=uint32)
```

Comment: `df` is a `structured` array, with a `compound dtype`.  Each `tuple` is actually a `record`, an element of the array.  It has 2 fields, not 2 columns.  Each element of an array has to have the same `dtype`.

Comment: Thanks, but how could I make it like df2 while keeping the property to specify types?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html.

Comment: You can make a 2d structured array, but each element will still be the 2 valued record specified by the `dtype`.